# pgmagick install on linux

Tags: linux, pgmagick

Im trying to install pgmagick on CentOS.

After i run `pip install pgmagick`i get some errors. After i checked log file, this is what i've got:

```
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pgmagick
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/root/build/pgmagick/setup.py", line 74, in <module>
        raise Exception("Magick++ not found")
    Exception: Magick++ not found
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "/root/build/pgmagick/setup.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise Exception("Magick++ not found")
Exception: Magick++ not found
----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /root/build/pgmagick
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 245, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1009, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 225, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 256, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /root/build/pgmagick
```

Am i missing something? How to make it work?

Comment: for me python-devel was missing. ```yum install python-devel```

Answer (score 38):

Just had this myself. For anyone visiting via Google from the future, you need two additional packages first:

```
sudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick++1-dev libboost-python-dev
```

Comment: On OSX : `brew install graphicsmagick` and `brew install boost-python`

Answer (score 4):

You are probably missing the `GraphicsMagick-c++-devel` package
(available from the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository).

Answer (score 0):

For Arch base distros you need to do:

```
sudo pacman -S libmagick boost graphicsmagick imagemagick
```

Answer (score 0):

by attention to the [official installation guidance](https://pgmagick.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#installation)

> pgmagick is available on UNIX-like systems. and depend on the
> following libraries.
>
> - [GraphicsMagick(Magick++)](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/) : graphing library. 1.3.5 and higher version.
> - [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) : wrap C++ code. 1.40 and higher version.

for [**debian**](https://pgmagick.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#debian)

```
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev libgraphicsmagick++1-dev
```

and if you have **another OS** you can check [installation page](https://pgmagick.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#installation)

after that you can install pgmagic with pip installation

```
$ pip install pgmagick
```